# Add value from data layer variable at the end of hyperlink

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I am trying to get a vlaue from a data layer variable and add it to the end of a hyperlink.
So if my hyperlink is https://www.somehyperlink.com and my variable is variable1 with value 23 i want the final hyperlink to be https://www.somehyperlink.com/23.

I've got this code, which is probably not the best way to do it, but I'm not sure how to replace the last part of it with the value from the variable:

```
(function () {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll( 'a[href="https://www.somehyperlink.com/replace"]')
    var searchString = "replace"
    var replacementString = "value-from-variable"

    links.forEach(function(link){
        var original = link.getAttribute("href");
        var replace = original.replace(searchString,replacementString)
        link.setAttribute("href",replace)
    })
})();
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer on how to populate the replacementString with the value of data layer variable.

Answer (score 0):

The code works, try to apply it in a **Custom HTML Tag** instead Custom Javascript variable.

Step 1:

- create a `Data Layer Variable` called i.e. '*DLV value to replace*' and assign the name of the variable in the `Data Layer Variable Name` field.

Step 2:

- apply the Data Layer Variable to your Custom HTML code.

See below:

```
<script>
    var links = document.querySelectorAll( 'a[href="https://www.somehyperlink.com/replace"]')
    var searchString = "replace"
    var replacementString = {{DLV value to replace}}

    links.forEach(function(link){
        var original = link.getAttribute("href");
        var replace = original.replace(searchString,replacementString)
        link.setAttribute("href",replace)
     })
</script>
```